# Find first instance of a string within a string

Tags: vb.net, pseudocode

I've got the following function that seems to work. This is in design code:

```
Method findFirst(word As String) As Integer

foundPosition As integer
Set foundPosition To -1
wordLen As integer
Set wordLen To len(word)
startingPoint As integer
Set startingPoint To (len(Text)- 1) - wordLen
For iPosition As integer From startingPoint To 0 Step -1
        If substring(iPosition, wordLen) = word Then
            foundPosition = iPosition
        End If      
    Next iPosition  
Return foundPosition

End Method
```

Implemented in `VB.NET` I've got the following:

```
Public Function findFirst(word As String) As Integer

    Dim foundPosition As Integer = -1
    Dim wordLen As Integer = word.Length
    Dim startingPoint As Integer = (fText.Length - 1) - wordLen

    For iPosition As Integer = startingPoint To 0 Step -1
        If fText.Substring(iPosition, wordLen) = word Then
            foundPosition = iPosition
        End If
    Next iPosition

    Return foundPosition

End Function
```

It returns the position of the parameter *word* within the field *fText*.
Is this a valid approach?
Does it break easily?
Are there better solutions?

Comment: [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx)?

Comment: And if you must re-implement it, run your loop in the other direction (from 0 to `startingPoint`, which you might want to rename) and change `foundPosition = iPosition` to `Return iPosition`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever your second comment is the snippet of information I was after ....had a feeling I'd missed something obvious.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm doing an Open University degree in the UK and the term we are being taught is "Design code" rather than "pseudocode"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Is this a valid approach?*

Yes it is a valid approuch, but it is not a feasible way to accomplish your task. By the way this kind of approuch will surely improve your `logical skills`.

*Are there better solutions?*

A built in `function` called [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) is available to acheive your task simply. It will return the `index` of the particular text in a `string` if it is available in it. otherwise it'll simply return `-1`

**Additional Info:**

Even though you starts searching the word from the end of the string fText, your code will return the index of its first occurance.Instead of doing that you can start your loop from the beginning like the code i given below. By the way You should use `Exit For`/`Return` to break the for loop at the end of the matching if statement inside that for loop.

```
For iPosition As Integer = 0 To len(Text)
        If fText.Substring(iPosition, wordLen) = word Then
            Return iPosition
        End If
Next iPosition
Return -1
```

Comment: ...my method is called `FindFirst` because I want to _find_ the _first_ instance. Your script works but I need to take out `Step - 1` and then I believe Damien's suggestion in the OP comments section is more elegant than using `Exit For`. Maybe you can edit your post so it becomes the answer?

Comment: @whytheq Oh, i just thought that you were looking to find the last index of that string. Now i just modified the code and explanation according to your requirement.

Comment: thanks Raju: I've tested and seems to work fine with just a single -1 in the `For`. Thanks again for the effort.

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably just want to use the built-in string method [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score 1):

There is a already implemented function to do that in .NET, try this:

```
Dim index As Integer = fText.IndexOf(word)
```

And if you want the last appearance:

```
index = fText.LastIndexOf(word)
```